# Extract Python function source text from the source code string

Tags: python

Suppose I have valid Python source code, as a string:

```
code_string = """
# A comment.
def foo(a, b):
  return a + b
class Bar(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.my_list = [
        'a',
        'b',
    ]
""".strip()
```

**Objective:** I would like to obtain the lines containing the source code of the function definitions, preserving whitespace. For the code string above, I would like to get the strings

```
def foo(a, b):
  return a + b
```

and

```
  def __init__(self):
    self.my_list = [
        'a',
        'b',
    ]
```

Or, equivalently, I'd be happy to get the line numbers of functions in the code string: `foo` spans lines 2-3, and `__init__` spans lines 5-9.

**Attempts**

I can parse the code string into its AST:

```
code_ast = ast.parse(code_string)
```

And I can find the `FunctionDef` nodes, e.g.:

```
function_def_nodes = [node for node in ast.walk(code_ast)
                      if isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef)]
```

Each `FunctionDef` node's `lineno` attribute tells us the first line for that function. We can estimate the last line of that function with:

```
last_line = max(node.lineno for node in ast.walk(function_def_node)
                if hasattr(node, 'lineno'))
```

but this doesn't work perfectly when the function ends with syntactic elements that don't show up as AST nodes, for instance the last `]` in `__init__`.

I doubt there is an approach that only uses the AST, because the AST fundamentally does not have enough information in cases like `__init__`.

I cannot use the `inspect` module because that only works on "live objects" and I only have the Python code as a string. I cannot `eval` the code because that's a huge security headache.

In theory I could write a parser for Python but that really seems like overkill.

A heuristic suggested in the comments is to use the leading whitespace of lines. However, that can break for strange but valid functions with weird indentation like:

```
def baz():
  return [
1,
  ]

class Baz(object):
  def hello(self, x):
    return self.hello(
x - 1)

def my_type_annotated_function(
  my_long_argument_name: SomeLongArgumentTypeName
) -> SomeLongReturnTypeName:
  # This function's indentation isn't unusual at all.
  pass
```

Comment: I suppose you could just iterate lines, and when one matches `^(\s*)def\s.*$`, extract that matched group (the leading whitespace) and then consume the line and all subsequent lines that `startWith(thatWhitespace)`

Comment: You mean, extract all subsequent lines that start with strictly more than that whitespace? Or else you'd also extract the following functions defined at the same indentation level

Comment: Oops, yes. You get the idea, anyway.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't work if the function has weird indentation inside, for example `def baz():\n  return [\n1,\n  ]`

Comment: Ah, I didn't even realise that was valid python. Looks like there's no simple text-processing method, then.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? I'm wondering if this is an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832), but if it's not, I'm curious to know.

Comment: Please trust that this is not an XY problem. That's all I can say unfortunately.

Comment: @wjandrea I'm not working on a code editor, but I'd imagine this would be relevant there. There are lots of things to do with programming tools or program analysis that require parsing or manipulating source code without actually running it.

Comment: If you first went through and made sure that opening parenthesis/brackets/braces always have the closing one on the same line, could you then use an indentation-based method? Because it shouldn't be too hard to find the closing paren/etc. and remove any newlines in the middle (potentially saving their locations first in case you want to insert them back in afterwards). Are there other ways an indentation-based approach could fail? (edit - includes quotes in the list too)

Comment: @Nathan This is getting close to an actual Python parser. You can have unmatched parens in comments or string literals, so this approach would have to understand the difference between normal code, comments, and strings. You have to take care of `#` that can appear in string literals, and escaped string delimiters, and string delimiters that appear in comments or multiline strings...

Comment: could you copy file, run it through **black** and use the normalized reformatted copy to be able to use indentation and generally find your way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Python 3.8, the `ast.FunctionDef` object (and all other AST node objects) have the [`end_lineno`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ast.html#ast.AST.end_lineno) field, so there is no more need for complicated solutions or brittle heuristics anymore.

A `FunctionDef` node `f` spans the 1-based lines from `f.lineno` to `f.end_lineno` inclusive. Function decorators are not included and should be handled separately using the AST.

Answer (score 5):

A much more robust solution would be to use the `tokenize` module. The following code can handle weird indentations, comments, multi-line tokens, single-line function blocks and empty lines within function blocks:

```
import tokenize
from io import BytesIO
from collections import deque
code_string = """
# A comment.
def foo(a, b):
  return a + b

class Bar(object):
  def __init__(self):

    self.my_list = [
        'a',
        'b',
    ]

  def test(self): pass
  def abc(self):
    '''multi-
    line token'''

def baz():
  return [
1,
  ]

class Baz(object):
  def hello(self, x):
    a = \
1
    return self.hello(
x - 1)

def my_type_annotated_function(
  my_long_argument_name: SomeLongArgumentTypeName
) -> SomeLongReturnTypeName:
  pass
  # unmatched parenthesis: (
""".strip()
file = BytesIO(code_string.encode())
tokens = deque(tokenize.tokenize(file.readline))
lines = []
while tokens:
    token = tokens.popleft()
    if token.type == tokenize.NAME and token.string == 'def':
        start_line, _ = token.start
        last_token = token
        while tokens:
            token = tokens.popleft()
            if token.type == tokenize.NEWLINE:
                break
            last_token = token
        if last_token.type == tokenize.OP and last_token.string == ':':
            indents = 0
            while tokens:
                token = tokens.popleft()
                if token.type == tokenize.NL:
                    continue
                if token.type == tokenize.INDENT:
                    indents += 1
                elif token.type == tokenize.DEDENT:
                    indents -= 1
                    if not indents:
                        break
                else:
                    last_token = token
        lines.append((start_line, last_token.end[0]))
print(lines)
```

This outputs:

```
[(2, 3), (6, 11), (13, 13), (14, 16), (18, 21), (24, 27), (29, 33)]
```

Note however that the continuation line:

```
a = \
1
```

is treated by `tokenize` as one line even though it is in fact two lines, since if you print the tokens:

```
TokenInfo(type=53 (OP), string=':', start=(24, 20), end=(24, 21), line='  def hello(self, x):\n')
TokenInfo(type=4 (NEWLINE), string='\n', start=(24, 21), end=(24, 22), line='  def hello(self, x):\n')
TokenInfo(type=5 (INDENT), string='    ', start=(25, 0), end=(25, 4), line='    a = 1\n')
TokenInfo(type=1 (NAME), string='a', start=(25, 4), end=(25, 5), line='    a = 1\n')
TokenInfo(type=53 (OP), string='=', start=(25, 6), end=(25, 7), line='    a = 1\n')
TokenInfo(type=2 (NUMBER), string='1', start=(25, 8), end=(25, 9), line='    a = 1\n')
TokenInfo(type=4 (NEWLINE), string='\n', start=(25, 9), end=(25, 10), line='    a = 1\n')
TokenInfo(type=1 (NAME), string='return', start=(26, 4), end=(26, 10), line='    return self.hello(\n')
```

you can see that the continuation line is literally treated as one line of `'    a = 1\n'`, with only one line number `25`. This is apparently a bug/limitation of the `tokenize` module unfortunately.

Comment: This looks promising. Are you sure it works for the "weird indentation" cases? I tried your code and it seems to break on all of the "weird indentation" functions I provided, extracting only the first part of each function.

Comment: Oops did not actually have any logic to handle weird indentation. Added now.

Comment: [This fails to handle line continuations.](https://ideone.com/WqTKjD) Looking for INDENT and DEDENT tokens (and checking for the single-logical-line case, where there is no INDENT) would probably be more robust.

Comment: @user2357112 Using INDENT and DEDENT was indeed my first thought too, although it wasn't immediately clear to me how to handle single-logical-line cases easily. I've now rewritten the code so that it uses INDENTs and DEDENTs, but noticed that a continuation line is treated as if it were a single line by `tokenize` even though it is literally multiple lines, so the line numbers returned by `tokenize` would be off in such a case. It's apparently a bug/limitation of the `tokenize` module unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I think a small parser is in order to try and take into account this weird exceptions:

```
import re

code_string = """
# A comment.
def foo(a, b):
  return a + b
class Bar(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.my_list = [
        'a',
        'b',
    ]

def baz():
  return [
1,
  ]

class Baz(object):
  def hello(self, x):
    return self.hello(
x - 1)

def my_type_annotated_function(
  my_long_argument_name: SomeLongArgumentTypeName
) -> SomeLongReturnTypeName:
  # This function's indentation isn't unusual at all.
  pass

def test_multiline():
    \"""
    asdasdada
sdadd
    \"""
    pass

def test_comment(
    a #)
):
    return [a,
    # ]
a]

def test_escaped_endline():
    return "asdad \
asdsad \
asdas"

def test_nested():
    return {():[[],
{
}
]
}

def test_strings():
    return '\""" asdasd' + \"""
12asd
12312
"asd2" [
\"""

\"""
def test_fake_def_in_multiline()
\"""
    print(123)
a = "def in_string():"
  def after().
    print("NOPE")

\"""Phew this ain't valid syntax\""" def something(): pass

""".strip()

code_string += '\n'


func_list=[]
func = ''
tab  = ''
brackets = {'(':0, '[':0, '{':0}
close = {')':'(', ']':'[', '}':'{'}
string=''
tab_f=''
c1=''
multiline=False
check=False
for line in code_string.split('\n'):
    tab = re.findall(r'^\s*',line)[0]
    if re.findall(r'^\s*def', line) and not string and not multiline:
        func += line + '\n'
        tab_f = tab
        check=True
    if func:
        if not check:
            if sum(brackets.values()) == 0 and not string and not multiline:
                if len(tab) <= len(tab_f):
                    func_list.append(func)
                    func=''
                    c1=''
                    c2=''
                    continue
            func += line + '\n'
        check = False
    for c0 in line:
        if c0 == '#' and not string and not multiline:
            break
        if c1 != '\\':
            if c0 in ['"', "'"]:
                if c2 == c1 == c0 == '"' and string != "'":
                    multiline = not multiline
                    string = ''
                    continue
                if not multiline:
                    if c0 in string:
                        string = ''
                    else:
                        if not string:
                            string = c0
            if not string and not multiline:
                if c0 in brackets:
                    brackets[c0] += 1
                if c0 in close:
                    b = close[c0]
                    brackets[b] -= 1
        c2=c1
        c1=c0

for f in func_list:
    print('-'*40)
    print(f)
```

output:

```
----------------------------------------
def foo(a, b):
  return a + b

----------------------------------------
  def __init__(self):
    self.my_list = [
        'a',
        'b',
    ]

----------------------------------------
def baz():
  return [
1,
  ]

----------------------------------------
  def hello(self, x):
    return self.hello(
x - 1)

----------------------------------------
def my_type_annotated_function(
  my_long_argument_name: SomeLongArgumentTypeName
) -> SomeLongReturnTypeName:
  # This function's indentation isn't unusual at all.
  pass

----------------------------------------
def test_multiline():
    """
    asdasdada
sdadd
    """
    pass

----------------------------------------
def test_comment(
    a #)
):
    return [a,
    # ]
a]

----------------------------------------
def test_escaped_endline():
    return "asdad asdsad asdas"

----------------------------------------
def test_nested():
    return {():[[],
{
}
]
}

----------------------------------------
def test_strings():
    return '""" asdasd' + """
12asd
12312
"asd2" [
"""

----------------------------------------
  def after():
    print("NOPE")
```

Comment: Writing a parser is hard. I haven't run your code but just by glancing at it, I think it fails for multiline strings (delimited with `"""`) and escaped string delimiters, and it doesn't understand comments (which may contain stray brackets or string delimiters).

Comment: Please do try it i should've included cases including strings and open/close brackets should not count if inside a string. EDIT: the escaped delimiters are an exception i will include it

Comment: You aren't checking for comments so there's no way you can tell if a close parenthesis should be counted or not (it shouldn't count if it's inside a comment).

Comment: Included both escaped characters and comments. Sorry i do tend to write parsers by starting simple and adding stuff as i find exception, not the best practice i realize

Answer (score 1):

Rather than reinventing a parser, I would use python itself.

Basically I would use the [compile()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#compile) built-in function, which can check if a string is a valid python code by compiling it. I pass to it a string made of selected lines, starting from each `def` to the farther line which does not fail to compile.

```
code_string = """
#A comment
def foo(a, b):
  return a + b

def bir(a, b):
  c = a + b
  return c

class Bar(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.my_list = [
        'a',
        'b',
    ]

def baz():
  return [
1,
  ]

""".strip()

lines = code_string.split('\n')

#looking for lines with 'def' keywords
defidxs = [e[0] for e in enumerate(lines) if 'def' in e[1]]

#getting the indentation of each 'def'
indents = {}
for i in defidxs:
    ll = lines[i].split('def')
    indents[i] = len(ll[0])

#extracting the strings
end = len(lines)-1
while end > 0:
    if end < defidxs[-1]:
        defidxs.pop()
    try:
        start = defidxs[-1]
    except IndexError: #break if there are no more 'def'
        break

    #empty lines between functions will cause an error, let's remove them
    if len(lines[end].strip()) == 0:
        end = end -1
        continue

    try:
        #fix lines removing indentation or compile will not compile
        fixlines = [ll[indents[start]:] for ll in lines[start:end+1]] #remove indentation
        body = '\n'.join(fixlines)
        compile(body, '<string>', 'exec') #if it fails, throws an exception
        print(body)
        end = start #no need to parse less line if it succeed.
    except:
        pass

    end = end -1
```

It is a bit nasty because of the `except` clause without specific exceptions, which is usually not recommended, but there is no way to know what may cause `compile` to fail, so I do not know how to avoid it.

This will prints

```
def baz():
  return [
1,
  ]
def __init__(self):
  self.my_list = [
      'a',
      'b',
  ]
def bir(a, b):
  c = a + b
  return c
def foo(a, b):
  return a + b
```

Note that the functions are printed in reverse order than those they appear inside  `code_strings`

This should handle even the weird indentation code, but I think it will fails if you have nested functions.

Answer (score 0):

Since Python 3.8, an `ast` node now has the `end_lineno` and `end_col_offset` to locate the exact end of the source code of a node, so a solution to the question has become trivial to implement:

```
import ast

code_string = """
# A comment.
def foo(a, b):
  return a + b
class Bar(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.my_list = [
        'a',
        'b',
    ]
""".strip()

code_lines = code_string.splitlines(keepends=True)
for node in ast.walk(ast.parse(code_string)):
    if isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef):
        lines = code_lines[node.lineno - 1:node.end_lineno]
        lines[0] = lines[0][node.col_offset:]
        lines[-1] = lines[-1][:node.end_col_offset]
        print(''.join(lines))
```

This outputs:

```
def foo(a, b):
  return a + b
def __init__(self):
    self.my_list = [
        'a',
        'b',
    ]
```