# how to capture string start from certain string and end from certain line and then store into list

Tags: python

What i want to do: Capture string start with def and also capture all method that belong to that
particular function and store it into list or tuple i not sure which is
suitable. The string i want to capture is the abc.py file.

Reason: Able to loop out on div to display

```
  #this is abc.py file
def hello_step0():
    element_wait_accid_click(self, ccc, ssss, accid, timeout=30)
    creation(self, driver, dataInput=dsds, CIwarning=False,IncidentCase="", notifications="")
    login()

def hello2_step1():
    delete()

def hello2_step2():
    delete()
```

What i already try:

```
with open("abc.py","r") as file:
    line = file.readlines()
    numOfline = len(line)
    extractedline.append(line)
    # print(numOfline)

    for i in range(len(line)):
        if line[i].strip().startswith('def'):
            print(str(line[i].strip().startswith('def')))
            extractedDEF.append(line[i].strip())

print(extractedDEF)
```

Comment: Can you give example of the string

Comment: actually the whole file consist of  `def hello_step`  is the string. I read the file with this code `line = file.readlines()`  and then print it become string format `print(str(line[i].strip().startswith('def')))`

Comment: The string that i want to capture is actually the abc.py file

Comment: Can you kindly share your final objective here? why do you extract all the def in the `abc.py`?

Comment: i want to create a python script that read and capture other python script that consist of `def` and the method other syntax inside it that belong to that particular `def` as well. Capturing each def and store into list. And using `json_dump` turn it become json object and pass it to ajax file to display each function on html.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract Python function source text from the source code string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54374296/extract-python-function-source-text-from-the-source-code-string)